# C - Struct in multiple files without header file

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I'm doing a college project in `C` which is quite strict in its requirements in that I'm not allowed to include any additional files or modify any header files.

I'm currently trying to implement a linked list to store some records and I need it to span over two `.c` files.  Currently to use global variables I've been declaring variables in `file1.c` and then in `file2.c` using `extern`. But how do I go about doing this for structures as I've always just added it to the `.h` file?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure your project is supposed to span more than 1 file?  Seems unlikely given the no .h file restriction.

Comment: "I need it to span over two .c files", like Michael said, are you sure about this?  It sounds like you've been given an interface to implement.  Can the the portion of the implementation that is concerned with the list be contained in a single .c file?

Comment: Yeah - I'm suppose to create 2 files One for the functions specified in a header file. With the rest of the functions inside of another file which include the user interface, along with the code that calls the functions in the first file.

Comment: In that case, you are probably over-engineering the problem.  My guess is the header specified has the interface needed to solve your problem once you implement its contents in the other file.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yeah I've had another look at it and you're correct. But I was just thinking that as the lecturer said in the document; "Use as many techniques as you can–including structures, pointers, dynamic storage etc. Less sophisticated methods will attract lower marks" that using a Linked List would be a good way of getting the higher marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the contents of what would be in the header file in each source file.

It is extremely difficult to discern why *anyone* would impose such a requirement.  It is rather like being required to build a wood frame house without any tools made of metal.  Any idea what it might be trying to teach?

Comment: Might be some sort of requirement for an automated assignment checker.

Answer (score 2):

It might seem daft to put such restrictions on your program, but I suspect your teacher is trying to get you to implement *encapsulation*.

Do you really need to use the struct in both files?  Try to have one .c file that handles the struct, and expose operations on that struct as function calls.

For example:  you might decide to have file2.c handling the struct.  Declare the struct in file2.c before any functions, after any `#include` statements - in other words where you would include the header file if you had one.

Then, if you need to access the struct from file1.c, call functions in file2.c to do the job for you.

Try to avoid global variables, pass parameters instead.  One typical global variable for a linked list might be the head (or anchor) pointer.  You can have that as a `static` global in file2.c (or whichever is handling the linked list) and keep it hidden - there should be no need to share.

Once all the operations on the linked list are encapsulated in one file it becomes independant of the user code, and can be used in other programs.